# Ignore Unknown Properties In Swagger Model

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger

We are using Swagger generated code for a restful server and models, and the problem is that the json payload can be updated with new properties at any point which will result in an error.

Typically, one can add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to ignore properties, but in this case the Swagger generated model is generated each build (and is read only).

How can we set Swagger model to ignore unknown properties?

Sample error:

```
Unrecognized field "abc" (class xyz.model.sample), not marked as ignorable ....
```

---

UPDATE based on Paul's response:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class ObjectMapperResolver implements 
ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>{
  private ObjectMapper mapper;

  public ObjectMapperResolver() {
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, 
    false);
  }

  @Override
  public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> cls) {
    return mapper;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `ContextResolver` to configure the `ObjectMapper` globally. There is a [`DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) that we can set to false, to tell Jackson not to worry about unknown properties.

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> cls) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

The Jackson JAX-RS provider will call this resolver to get the `ObjectMapper` it uses for deserialization.

If you are using scanning to register your resources and providers, then this class should automatically be registered because of the `@Provider` annotation. If you are not using scanning, then you need to make sure that you register this resolver, or else it won't be used.

---

#### Edit

If the Swagger codegen is already creating a `ContextResolver`, what you can do is just instantiate it in *your* resolver, and get the `ObjectMapper` from *that* resolver instead of creating your own mapper. This ensures that any configurations to the `ObjectMapper` made in the generated resolver still take effect. Then add a `@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` to the class so it is guaranteed to be used over the generated one, should the generated one also be registered.

```
@Provider
@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class ObjectMapperResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperResolver() {
        JSON swaggerResolver = new JSON(); 
        mapper = swaggerResolver.getContext(null);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> cls) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. There is already ContextResolver in JSON.java that Swagger generates each build. From mine: import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;

@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2018-09-06T14:11:35.715-07:00")
public class JSON implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> { ....

Comment: What does it do? Is it needed?

Comment: If it's needed, what you can do is just instantiate it in your resolver, and get the `ObjectMapper` from _that_ resolver and just use that one instead of creating your own. Then add a `@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` to the class so it is guaranteed to be used.

Comment: It's generated automatically by swagger, I'm guessing to parse the json document. Can I override it? Also, in you answer I get an error from `public ObjectMapperResolver` saying that return type required.

Comment: There shouldn't be an error. I don't get any... Look at my previous comment for what you should do, as far as "overriding it"

Comment: If you can't get it to work, can use post the code for it?

Comment: I meant the generated code. See my update. Assuming `JSON` is the generated class, this is what you should do. And just make sure to register your resolver.